# Lumia 925 with WP 8.1 not executing voice commands, always searches instead

Tags: 8.1, lumia-925, speech

Whenever I try to use any voice command, the phone resolves the spoken word correctly, but instead of executing it, it always searches for it.
E.g. I say *"Call <name>"*, it will go *"Searching for 'Call <name>'"* and so on with all the commands.

What did I miss? What can I do?

Comment: are you using cortana?

Comment: @Thomas: Good point. It seems my phone doesn't have Cortana installed. I go into settings/applications and there is no Cortana menu item where I could torni it on. WP 8.1 on Lumia 925, UK. Any ideas how to install it?

Comment: Cortana can't be "installed", it just shows up depending on your region and language settings. Setting it to USA will work definately, I think UK will get it quite soon (thought they'd had it already..). Have you checked if your speech language is set properly?